# Problema al insertar datos JSON en PostgreSQL con PHP

Tags: php, sql, json, postgresql, paypal

necesito guardar un array json almacenado en la variable `$respuestaVenta` en la columna `datos_paypal` de la tabla `ventas`, con tipo de dato JSONB. Al ejecutar la sentencia desde PHP me salta el siguiente error en el navegador:

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca
>   de «{» LINE 1: update ventas set
>   datos_paypal={"id":"PAYID-L3KO6MA8TV36490S... ^ in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\web\php\verificador.php on line 93

He probado a cambiar el tipo de dato de la columna a JSON, VARCHAR, TEXT y sigue sin funcionar, muchas gracias por la ayuda. Dejo el código de la sentencia SQL en PHP:

```
if ($estadoTransac=="approved") {
            $msgPaypal="<h3>Pago aprobado.</h3>";
            echo $msgPaypal;

            //$strRespuestaVenta=strval($respuestaVenta);
            //SI SE HA APROBADO EL PAGO, ACTUALIZAMOS LA COLUMNA datos_paypal DE LA TABLA VENTAS
            $actDatosPaypal="update ventas set datos_paypal=$respuestaVenta, estado='aprobado' where id_venta=$claveVenta";
            $operacion3=pg_query($bd, $actDatosPaypal) or die('la consulta ha fallado: '.preg_last_error());


        }
```

Comment: y no has probado a poner comillas simples en el campo de la consulta? ten en cuenta que un json es UNA CADENA con un formato (en concreto json).

Comment: probé también y sigue saltando el mismo error, pero no acabo de entender el porqué ya que  la columna de la tabla es del mismo tipo, por lo que no debería dar problemas al ejecutar la sentencia.

Answer (score 0):

Te faltan las comillas en la sentencia SQL. A mí me gusta separar las variables para evitar tener que usar {} cuando hay símbolos especiales, pero supongo que eso va por gustos.

Sería algo así:

```
$actDatosPaypal="update ventas set datos_paypal='".$respuestaVenta ."', estado='aprobado' where id_venta='".$claveVenta ."'";
```

Fíjate que después de datos_paypal= hay una comilla simple (') seguida de una comilla doble (").

Answer (score 0):

Conseguí insertar el dato en la columna pero tuve que cambiarla a tipo 'text' y poner un carácter como valor por defecto. Aun así, parece que la cadena json proporcionada por paypal contiene un carácter no legible desde el tipo de codificación de mi base de datos (UTF8), por lo que al realizar select a todas las columnas incluyendo datos_paypal me salía el siguiente mensaje de error por parte del sgbd:

ERROR:  carácter con secuencia de bytes 0xef 0xbf 0xbd en codificación «UTF8» no tiene equivalente en la codificación «WIN1252»

He estado investigando y para cambiar la codificación de la base de datos hay que realizar una serie de comandos los cuales vienen explicados paso a paso en el segundo enlace. De nuevo, gracias por la ayuda, esta comunidad me ha salvado de muchas jajaja.

Dejo por aquí un par de enlaces que pueden ser de ayuda:
[Ver el tipo de codificación de nuestra base de datos:](https://todopostgresql.com/como-averiguar-y-establecer-el-encoding-en-postgres/)

[Cambiar codificación base de datos PostgreSQL](http://www.stalingp.org/cambiar-codificacion-postgresql/)